# Imagen en canvas con on touch event

Tags: android, android-studio, eventos, drag-and-drop

me encontré con un problema. Necesito dibujar una imagen(Drawable) en canvas y luego ser capaz de moverla por la pantalla con un on touch.
La imagen aparece pero no logro hacer que se mueva.

Tengo este código para hacer que se mueva que me funcionaba bien cuando lo usaba en el MainActivity pero no logro hacer que funcione en la clase nueva que cree.

En que estoy fallando? Esta es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Gracias

```
public class Juego extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

Drawable esfera;

public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    esfera = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.esfera);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int ancho = 200;
    int alto = 200;
    esfera.setBounds(0, 0, alto, ancho);
    esfera.draw(canvas);
}

float x,y = 0.0f;
boolean moving = false;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            moving = true;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (moving) {
                x = event.getRawX() - esfera.getWidth() / 2;
                y = event.getRawY() - esfera.getHeight() * 3 / 2;
                esfera.setX(x);
                esfera.setY(y);
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            moving = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: getWidth() y getHeight() no se puede obtener del Drawable.

Answer (score 2):

Me acabo de encontrar con esta pregunta de hace cinco años, y estoy mirando precisamente éste tema, cuelgo uma posible la solución

```
//creamos la clase mover dibujo
class MoverDibujo extends View {

    //creamos el boton cerrar
    Button btnCerrar;

    //creamos un array con la posición x de tres círculos
    float[] x = {50, 130, 250};
    //creamos un array con la posicion y de tres círculos
    float[] y = {50, 100, 150};
    //creamos un tercer array con el radio diferente de tres círculos
    float[] radio = {50, 100, 200};

    //creamos un array de paint, como si fueran pinceles
    Paint paint[] = new Paint[3];
    //creamos otro pincel para dibujar el texto
    Paint t;

    //variable entera a -1
    int circulo = -1;
    //variable string con el texto mueve figura
    String txt = "Mueve figura";

    //el constructor de la clase
    public MoverDibujo(Context context){
        super(context);

        //damos la configuración al primer paint
        paint[0] = new Paint();
        paint[0].setAntiAlias(true);
        paint[0].setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint[0].setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint[0].setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //configuración del segundo paint
        paint[1] = new Paint();
        paint[1].setAntiAlias(true);
        paint[1].setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint[1].setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint[1].setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        //configuración del tercer paint
        paint[2] = new Paint();
        paint[2].setAntiAlias(true);
        paint[2].setStrokeWidth(6);
        paint[2].setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint[2].setColor(Color.GREEN);

        //configuración del paint de texto
        t = new Paint();
        t.setAntiAlias(true);
        t.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        t.setTextSize(50);
    }

    //método onDraw
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        //ponemos un fondo negro para el lienzo
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        //configuramos el texto a dibujar
        canvas.drawText(txt, 150, 130, t);

        //bucle for que dibuja los círculos tomando los datos de los arrays
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            canvas.drawCircle(x[i], y[i], radio[i], paint[i]);
        }
    }

    //método on touch
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evento){
        //determinamos la posición de la pulsación
        float getX = evento.getX();
        float getY = evento.getY();
        int accion = evento.getAction();

        //si pulsamos
        if (accion == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                double cenX = getX - x[i];
                double cenY = getY - y[i];

                //si la distancia de la pulsación está próxima a un círculo
                float distancia = (float) Math.sqrt(cenX * cenX + cenY * cenY);
                if (distancia <= radio[i]){
                    /ns selecciona el círculo
                    circulo = i;
                    if (circulo == 0) {
                        //escribe el texto con el color del circulo que corresponde, e´ste para el blanco
                        txt = "Moviendo círculo Blanco";
                    }
                    else if (circulo == 1) {
                        txt = "Moviendo círculo Amarillo";
                    }
                    else if (circulo == 2) {
                        txt = "Moviendo círculo Verde";
                    }
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
        //si desplazamos la pulsación, moverá el círculo correspondiente a la pulsación más próxima al circulo elegido
        if (accion == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if (circulo > - 1){
                x[circulo] = getX;
                y[circulo] = getY;
                invalidate();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```